# What is the cheapest 3D printer that you can get right now?

Tags: desktop-printer

What is the cheapest (**desktop**) 3D printer that you can get right now?

Is there a current price list (with different vendors)?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. Suggestions for purchasing printers should not be asked on this site.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to repost the question asking for ROI comparison of marketed printers, instead of which printer to purchase?

Comment: @tbm0115 I don't think so. Printer comparisons inevitably become outdated with new models coming to market.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden True. Is there at least another site we can refer OP to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The peer-based 3D printing service called [3D Hubs](https://www.3dhubs.com/) conducted a survey of its users and which printers they use and suggest. This survey's results are [here](https://www.3dhubs.com/best-3d-printer-guide?utm_source=customerio&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=hubs_surveyed).

I recall a similar Google Group conducting a similar survey a year or so ago, I'll search for the link to that as well a little later.

Comment: Did you manage to find that link to the Google groups survey?

Comment: You know it's made by a 3D printing service (who make money by people not having their own printer) by calling a 1000$ delta and the CR-10 "budget" printers.